# Trying to show image in admin grid in custom module

Tags: image, magento, grid, admin

while i trying to show image in admin grid in custom module it show error like

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on a non-object in D:\Program Files\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php on line 291
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a one Block File in Adminhtml Folder Say Renderer and in that you can create a file call Image.php

In that file write a function

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row){
        $mediaurl=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
        $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        return '<p style="text-align:center;padding-top:10px;"><img src="'.$mediaurl.DS.$value.'"  style="width:100px;height:200px;text-align:center;"/></p>';
    }
```

an call this function in grid.php

```
$this->addColumn("thumbnailimage", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("modulename")->__("Image"),
                "index" => "thumbnailimage",
                "renderer" =>"Companyname_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Image",
                ));
```

Comment: Just a note that the renderer in Image.php should extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract`

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this is to check the path to render class in _prepareColumns() function.

For exmaple, In my case the path to the render class was wrong. Check the below code:

```
$this->addColumn('img', array(
            'header' => 'Image',
            'align' => 'left',
            'index' => 'img',
            'width'     => '70',
            'renderer' => 'demo/adminhtml_grid_renderer_img'
        ));
```

Here the renderer attribute holds the path to your render class, review it. IF the path is wrong at that time this type of error is shown.